# MongoDB JS, Find and return

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I couldn't find anything on this, apologies if someone asked this question before.

I'm confused as to how I can go about finding a value and returning the entire collection.

This is what my database looks like,

[Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNH7x.png)

I'd like to be able to get "RobloxID" from the "DiscordID", meaning.. if I find the DiscordID, how could I get the RobloxID from it?

Current code.

```
MongoClient.connect(mongoURL, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mydb");
  //var myobj = { RobloxID: 69420, DiscordID: "164829153449738241"};
  dbo.collection("LinkedAccounts").find({DiscordID: "164829153449738241"}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    db.close();
  });
});
```

Comment: Whats inside `result` ? Why is that not what you want?

Comment: This is what's inside *result* https://pastebin.com/raw/g5RbEd0s, it can't see a way to get the RobloxID from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes have a patience and [read docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb#find-all-documents) carefully:

```
MongoClient.connect(
  mongoURL, 
  { useNewUrlParser: true }, 
  (err, db) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    const dbo = db.db("mydb");

    const linkedAccounts = dbo.collection("LinkedAccounts");

    linkedAccounts
      .find({DiscordID: "164829153449738241"})
      .toArray((error, docs) => {
        console.log(docs);
        db.close();
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

`find(...)` results in a Cursor, which is a "connection" to the database that allows you to go over the results step by step, or apply filters etc. to it. To finally execute the cursor and get all the results, call `.toArray()` on it ([docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html#toarray)):

```
  collection.find({ DiscordID: "1234" }).toArray(function(error, result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

As it seems you only want to get the first occurence, which you can get with `findOne`:

```
  collection.findOne({ DiscordID: "1234" }, function(error, result) {
    console.log(result.RobloxID);
  });
```